# Locus of centre of ellipse sliding along coordinate axes?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> An ellipse of major and minor axes of length √3 and 1 respectively, slides along the co-ordinate axes and always remains confined in the first quadrant. The locus of the centre of the ellipse will be the arc of a circle the length of which is:

The answer given is 0.52. In the solution it is given that locus of centre is $x^2+y^2=1$ and difference in parametric angles at two extreme positions is π/6. (This is because the two extreme positions are $tan^{-1} (π/6)$ and $tan^{-1} (π/3)$). I am actually having difficulty understanding why locus of centre is $x^2+y^2=1$. I understand that at the two extreme positions(major axis parallel to x axis and y axis respectively) the distance of the centre from the origin is 1 ($1^2 = (√3/2)^2 + (1/2)^2$), but what about the other positions in between these two? I only have an intuition about the fact that the distance of centre from origin remains 1 as ellipse slides, and would welcome some clearer guidance.

Comment: See the animation of another answer [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889450/extrema-of-ellipse-from-parametric-form/1890278#1890278).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can look at it in another way. We know that for an ellipse, if two mutually perpendicular tangents are drawn, then the intersection of these tangents lies on **[director circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Director_circle)** $x^2+y^2=a^2+b^2 = 1$. This equation is valid when $C(0,0)$ is centre of ellipse.

Now here, the origin of coordinates $O(0,0)$ is fixed, but the centre $C$ of ellipse  is moving relative to it, so it will also lie on same curve, that is $x^2+y^2 = 1$.

For arc length I think your approach is proper.

Comment: Samjoe. Very nice!